# UITextField attributes : keyboards

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode9

In Xcode's storyboard, I was setting the keyboard Type as E-mail Address. I noticed that there is also a `Content-Type` (that can also have an Email Adress content type) drop down. What is the purpose of it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KIiN.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyboard type sets just the keyboard to be shown.

The content type is more general.

The UITextField implements UITextInputTraits protocol. In this, the Content Type is used to indicate the semantic meaning of the text field. It can be used to indicate the sorts of auto-corrections that might occur, for example.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits for more details of this protocol.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation :

> The textContentType property is to provide the keyboard with extra information about the semantic intent of the text document.

They `keyboardType` property on the other hand determines the keyboard layout that will be presented.